# Java - Start Button and new JFrame

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, actionlistener

I have to make sure that when one presses the start game button opens the gaming frame.

This is the menu:

[image]

This is the controller class:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JRadioButton source = (JRadioButton)e.getSource();
    JButton sourceButton = (JButton)e.getSource();

    if(source.isSelected() && source.getText().equals("Custom")){
        MenuView.heightLabel.setEnabled(true);
        MenuView.height.setEnabled(true);

        MenuView.widthLabel.setEnabled(true);
        MenuView.width.setEnabled(true);

        MenuView.minesLabel.setEnabled(true);
        MenuView.mines.setEnabled(true);
    }
    else{
        MenuView.heightLabel.setEnabled(false);
        MenuView.height.setEnabled(false);

        MenuView.widthLabel.setEnabled(false);
        MenuView.width.setEnabled(false);

        MenuView.minesLabel.setEnabled(false);
        MenuView.mines.setEnabled(false);
    }

    if(source.getText().equals("Beginner")){
        if(sourceButton.getText().equals("Start Game")){
            MenuView.fullRandom = new FullRandomGrid(ROW_BEGINNER, COLUMN_BEGINNER, MINE_BEGINNER);
            Frame frame = new Frame(MenuView.fullRandom);
            frame.setSize(270, 380);
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setVisible(true);

        }
    }   
}
```

The problem is that when I press `Start Game` I have this exception:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   javax.swing.JButton cannot be cast to javax.swing.JRadioButton

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Why would you expect **e.getSource()** to return instance of **JButton** and **JRadioButton** too?? JRadioButton has no **inheritance** relationship with JButton, meaning the **object** returned by e.getSource() could only be a **JButton** or **JRadioButton** instance, which in my opinion is JButton though, because the user pressed a JButton :)

Comment: *"..new JFrame.."* See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in this line :

```
JRadioButton source = (JRadioButton)e.getSource();
```

> Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a
>   subclass of which it is not an instance.

`JRadioButton` is not an subclass of `e.getSource()`, so a ClassCastException will be thrown.

---

```
JRadioButton source = (JRadioButton)e.getSource();
JButton sourceButton = (JButton)e.getSource();
```

How `e.getSource()` can be cast in both, no child parent relationship.

Comment: you've reference of your `JRadioButton` globally ? If not make it and use in your method.

Comment: Take a look of this part `MenuView.heightLabel`, heightLabel is static reference of `JLabel` so you're using with class name, In same way create reference of `JRadioButton` and use in `actionPerformed` method instead of `source` variable

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in line `JRadioButton source = (JRadioButton)e.getSource();` - you are pressing the JButton object, which causes event and then you are casting wrong JButton type  to JRadioButton.